# Create derived custom types using New-Module -AsCustomObject

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to create a custom type dervied from another custom type using the New-Module cmdlet?

Example:

```
function New-Shape
{
    New-Module -ArgumentList $args -AsCustomObject {
        param (
            [string]$position
            )
        {
            $script:position = $position
        }

        Export-ModuleMember -Variable Position
    }
}

function New-Circle
{
    # How to derive Circle from Shape?
    New-Module -ArgumentList $args -AsCustomObject {
        param (
            [string]$radius
            )
        {
            $script:radius = $radius
        }

        Export-ModuleMember -Variable Radius
    }
}

# So that we can do

$circle = New-Circle $position $radius

$circle.Position
$circle.Radius
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK this doesn't work in plain PowerShell (without going to some lengths at least), but it should be possible with [this](http://psclass.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Interesting, curious how they implemented the DSL.

Answer (score 0):

There is powerful magic in dynamic modules, but they sometimes can behave oddly. However, this seems to work. I've added a scriptblock as well as a noteproperty just to prove that it is viable. Be careful about arrays.

```
    function New-Shape
    {
        New-Module -ArgumentList $args -AsCustomObject {
            param (
                [string]$position
            )
            {
                $script:position = $position
            }

            Export-ModuleMember -Variable Position
        }
    }

    function New-Circle
    {
        param
        (
            [string]$position,
            $radius
        )

        $circle = new-shape $position
        $circle | Add-Member -NotePropertyName radius -NotePropertyValue $radius
        $circle | Add-Member -PassThru -MemberType ScriptProperty -Name "Circumference" -force -Value {
            $this.radius * [math]::Pi * 2
        }
    }

    $MyCircle = new-circle '34,3'  2.56
    $myCircle.position
    $myCircle.radius
    $MyCircle.Circumference
    $MyCircle | gm
```